# How can I perform analytical operations along with join in Mosaic Decisions?

Tags: expression, left-join, analytics, mosaic-decisions

While joining the two tables I need to perform some **analytical operations** on the columns.

Example,

```
left outer join $(CORE_DB_NAME).GLOBAL_DIMENSION_CORE.plant_d loc on
upper(trim(COALESCE(loc.PLANT_NUMBER,'-1'))) =
upper(trim(COALESCE(afru.werks,'-1')))
```

How can I achieve this in Mosaic Decisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this in Mosaic Decisions, **Transformer Node** can be used to transform the data by using the various functions available in it.

Considering the above scenario, below functions available under `String Functions` in the transformer node can be used to process the data and then perform join operation on it

```
UPPER()

TRIM()
 
COALESCE()
```